# SC_Analytics_Cookie is the same for all users

Tags: xconnect

I am using Sitecore 10.1 and when I try to access the published site all the  analytics cookies in different browsers/ machines map to the same user.

Any clue how to trouble shoot this issue?

Comment: Can you confirm that you open same site with two different browsers and the cookie value is the same?

Comment: yes the cookie maps to the same user in xconnect although the site is accessed from different machines

Comment: Could you post your httpRequestBegin pipelines to the question? You might have a custom pipeline that does something it shouldn't. You can see it from showconfig.aspx page

Comment: Is the response being cached by a CDN? If so the cookie will be in the cached response.